How can I show the output from a $(command) that gets called inside a .ps1 script
I'm currently trying using PowerShell script to automate my applications daily maintenance.
So I have inside something similar to this pseudo code:
statement
statement
$variable
$(command $variable) #edited
# this is external .bat file that I'm passing the variable as param.
statement

The thing is that subcommand gets executed but does not throw his output onto the main thread, so I get a "pause" while it gets executed.
normal output
normal output
**wait while subcommand gets executed**
normal output

How can I capture the subcommand output into the main stdout of my script?
I researched a bit, and the Tee-Object came up, but I think that's mostly for writing a file at the same time while you show your thing over stdout, useful for logging purposes and maybe needed in the future.
For my specific case I don't really now if Tee-Object is something that I could use.

If I understand the question, without any given code, you want to use & { } (or a function) instead of $( ) to see the output live?  (But why use $( ) at all, unless you want to combine multiple statements?)
$(1;sleep 1;2;sleep 1;3)  # dumps output all at once at the end
1
2
3

& {1;sleep 1;2;sleep 1;3}  # see output as it's running
1
2
3



Preface:

The answer below, as well as Jeff Zeitlin's, are based on an earlier form of the question with an accidentally different premise:

How to also print / send to the success output stream output from a command that is passed to another command as an argument, enclosed in $(...)
(command $(command)), ideally in streaming fashion (emitting each output object as soon as it becomes avavilable).


To address the current form of the question:

Using $(...), the subexpression operator, has the side effect of collecting all output up front before outputting it to the success output stream.

A stand-alone command, such as batch-file call (whether with or without arguments), does not require enclosure in $(...); $(...)'s primary use is inside expandable (interpolating), double-quoted strings ("...").

Thus, simply omitting $(...) should result in the desired streaming behavior.

If you want so-called language statements (e.g., a switch statement) to provide input to another command in a pipeline (which isn't directly supported) with streaming behavior, enclose them in a script block ({ ... }) and invoke the latter with &, the call operator; you can also use the same technique to provide input from multiple commands that way; e.g.:
 # Enclosure in & { ... } provides streaming output from
 # the enclosed command / statements, as evidenced by the fact
 # that the first Get-Date call's output prints right away,
 # before pausing.
 & { Get-Date; pause; Get-Date } | Write-Output






Answer to the original question:
Jeff Zeitlin's helpful answer shows you how to capture all output of the command inside $(...) first, then output it to the success output stream (PowerShell's stdout analog), and finally pass it as an argument, as before.
Alternatively, IF:

Your intent is to stream the output produced by the command inside $(...), as soon as each output object is produced, and ...
... it is sufficient to produce to-display (terminal) output only, and ...
... assuming you're using PowerShell (Core) 7 (see this answer for a workaround for Windows PowerShell),

you can use Tee-Object and pass the console / terminal device as the argument to the -FilePath parameter, which then prints each input object to the terminal while also outputting it to the success output stream for further programmatic processing:
Here's a simple example:
# PowerShell 7
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $(
  1, 2, 3 | Tee-Object -FilePath ($IsWindows ? '\\.\CON': '/dev/tty')
)

The sample command (array 1, 2, 3) prints to the terminal in streaming fashion, before Write-Host receives the collected output at once, as a single argument.
Note that, as Jeff notes, use of $(...) may not be necessary to enclose your command, allowing the more efficient, side effect-free (...) to be used instead; indeed, in the case at hand, because the command consists of only a single pipeline, (...) is enough - see this answer for additional information.

Thank you so much, indeed the solutions to my dumb issue was using & {} structure instead of $( ).
Thank you so much for your time, and patience.

The way you’ve written your pseudoscript, $(command) is a parameter to the third statement. Either statement must output whatever it receives as the first parameter, or you must separately accommodate your need to print the output.
To do the latter, assign it to a variable, print the variable, and then pass the variable as the parameter to statement:
statement1
statement2
$s3param = $(command)   # capture the output of command
$s3param                # print the (captured) output of command
statement3 $s3param     # pass the (captured) output of command as a parameter to statement3
statement4
⋮

(Depending on the command, you may not need the $() around it)

Jeff you're totally right. My sub command is not a parameter fed into the statement is a statement itself on its own, but it requires indeed to be inside the $() as it's an external .bat to be called.
